# Embedding lookup with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

While using the function `tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params, ids)`, when the ids is  a `tf.constant([])`  the  embedding is good every params correspond to its ids successfully, but if I use a random uniform distribution the result is not correct ?

Comment: What do you mean by using "random uniform distribution"? Where do you use it? Please provide an example

Comment: Whene I use tf.random_uniforme() instead of tf.constant() to generate Ids for tf.nn.embedding() the result won't be the same !

Comment: The ids should be integers, not floats. Please read the docs.

Comment: Indeed, I did it, no improvement!